# Node.js chat without Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I just started learning Node.js and as I was learning about the `fs.watchFile()` method, I was wondering if a chat website could be efficiently built with it (and `fs.writeFile()`), against for example Socket.IO which is stable, but I believe not 100% stable (several fallbacks, including flash).

Using `fs.watchFile` could perhaps also be used to keep histories of the chats quite simply (as JSON would be used on the spot).

The chat files could be formatted in JSON in such a way that only the last chatter's message is brought up to the DOM (or whatever to make it efficient to 'fetch' messages when the file gets updated).

I haven't tried it yet as I still need to learn more about Node, and even more to be able to compare it with Socket.IO, but what's your opinion about it? Could it be an efficient/stable way of doing chats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing chat files in flatfile JSON is not a good idea, because if you are going to manipulating the files, you would have to parse and serialize entire JSON objects, which would become very slow as the size of the JSON object increased. The watch methods for the filesystem module also don't work on all operating systems.

You also can't compare Node.js to Socket.IO because they are entirely different things. Socket.IO is a Node module for realtime transport between the browser and the server. What you need is dependent on what you're doing. If you need chat history, then you should be using a database such as MongoDB or MySQL. Watching files for changes is not an efficient way and you should just send messages as they received.

In conclusion no, using `fs.watchFile()` and `fs.writeFile()` is a very bad idea, because race conditions would occur due to concurrent file writes, besides that `fs.watchFile()` uses polling to check if a file has changed. You should instead use Socket.IO and push messages to other clients / store them in a database *as they are received*.

Comment: I see, so that would similar to using AJAX with setIntervals to poll data as it changes, kind of going back to stone age. I'll use socket.io directly and store chats in MongoDB. Thanks.

Comment: That's a good idea - Socket.IO is also battle tested, and can scale horizontally with publish/subscribe stores such as Redis. Good luck!

Comment: +1 from me. Also worth noting that Socket.io can be used, if you want, as a transport between two servers as well :)

Answer (score 4):

`fs.watchFile()` can be used to watch changes to the file in the local filesystem (on the server). This will not solve your need to update all clients chat messages in their browsers. You'll still need web sockets, AJAX or Flash for that (or socket.io, which handles all of those).

What you could typically do in the client is to try to use Web Sockets. If browser does not support them, try to use XMLHttpRequest. If that fails, fallback to Flash. It's a lot of programming to do, and it has to be handled by node.js server as well. Socket.io does that for you.

Also, socket.io is pretty stable. Fallback to Flash is not due to it's instability but due to lack of browser support for better solutions (like Web Sockets).

Comment: Thanks, I'll be going directly with socket.io then

Comment: How do you do chat with AJAX? poll the server continuously ?

Comment: @nmtuan To be clear - one doesn't chat "with AJAX", but rather "over AJAX" - which means that AJAX is not a side in the communication, but the means for the communication to happen. So to get notifications from the server to the browser, you would typically use WebSockets, AJAX, or Flash. In case of AJAX, yeah, server would be polled continuously using long-lived requests, where server would not respond until it has some new data for the browser (well, it's a bit more complicated than that because of timeouts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use long pooling method using javascript setTimeout and setInterval

**long pooling**

basically long pooling working on Ajax reqest and server responce time.

server will respond after a certain time (like after 50 seconds ) if there is not notification or message  else it will respond with data and from client side when client gets response client javascript makes another request for new update and wait till response this process is endless until server is running